# Back navigation not working in android App

Tags: selenium, appium

I am trying to use the following commands for clicking on back button of my android app using appium.
driver.

```
((PressesKey) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
        //((PressesKey) driver).pressKeyCode(4);        //((PressesKey)
driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent().withKey(AndroidKey.BACK));
```

None of the command seem to work.Please suggest any command to perform the back operation

Answer (score 1):

Please try this command below.

```
webdriver.navigate().back();
```